# Ambiguous call for overloaded operator for templated class

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

I have a templated class for volume objects where `operator+=` is implemented as a member function and the `operator+`is implemented as non-member functions:

```
template <typename Class>
Class operator+(Class c1, const Class& c2) {
   return c1 += c2;
}

// Add a constant to every element in the volume
template <typename Class, typename dataType>
Class operator+(Class c, dataType constant) {
   return c += constant;
}

template <typename Class, typename dataType>
Class operator+(dataType constant, Class c) {
   return c += constant;
}
```

Then I try to compile the following:

```
volume + 1.3;
```

where volume is a derived type from the templated volume class.
This gives me the following error:

```
error: ambiguous overload for ‘operator+’ in ‘volume + 1.3’
```

Why is the call ambiguous?

Comment: Can you show at least declaration of your class? The exact declaration of the operators depend on it.

Comment: Why can't you just use your class as one of the arguments, and let the other be templated? I.e. `template<typename Vt> YourClass operator+(YourClass a, const Vt value) { return a += value; }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second template could be inferred with `Class = typeof(volume)` and `dataType = double`, or your third template can be inferred with `dataType = typeof(volume)` and `Class = double`. The compiler can't choose between them, even though quite possibly the third template would fail to instantiate.

I'm assuming that `volume` has a user-defined type. If it has a built-in type, then I don't *think* the call would be ambiguous, because for the purpose of operator overload resolution only, there are "real" functions `double operator+(double, double);` etc, that would be selected before the templates are even considered.

Comment: Ahh, it seems obvious in retrospect. Presumably the two operator overloads were intended to be partial template specialisations, and instead have ended up remaining totally generic.

Comment: @Rook: something along those lines. My guess is that because there are a lot of different types that `volume` could be, this seemed easier than trying to define more specific templates for `operator+`.

Answer (score 2):

Assume Volume is the name of your class.

```
Volume volume;
```

When volume + 1.3 needs to be resolved, compiler looks for suitable methods.
And it finds two of them.

1. template 
   Class operator+(Class c, dataType constant)
2. template 
   Class operator+(dataType constant, Class c)

Why?

The literal 'Class' in these definitions has no significance. It is *not* at all related to the 'Volume' class, even if you intend to happen so.

So, compiler sees it as:
1.

```
template <typename X, typename Y>
X operator+(X c, Y constant)
```

1. template 
   Z operator+(Z constant, X c)

So, both of these are equally good enough for the compiler for the line

```
volume+1.3
```

i.e : from (1) :

```
Volume operator+(Volume c, double constant)
```

from (2) :

```
Volume operator+(Volume constant, double c)
```

Now, it is ambiguous for the compiler.

Solution : I can only see the solution that you have to define these operator for each volume type separately.

Answer (score 0):

Others explained why your code does not work. But in general it is a very bad idea to write function templates that accept *any* argument type. That's only asking for ambiguities.

If you have a list of "volume" types you want to have operator+ for, you can make them inherit a common base class, which you can then use as parameter type in your template.

```
template<typename T>
struct VolumeBase { 
  T copy() const { return get(); }
  T const& get() const { return static_cast<T const&>(*this); }
};

template <typename Class, typename Class>
Class operator+(VolumeBase<Class> const& c, VolumeBase<Class> const& c1) {
   return c.copy() += c1.get();
}

template <typename Class, typename dataType>
Class operator+(VolumeBase<Class> const& c, dataType constant) {
   return c.copy() += constant;
}

template <typename Class, typename dataType>
Class operator+(dataType constant, VolumeBase<Class> const& c) {
   return c.copy() += constant;
}
```

Unfortunately you have moved the argument copy into the body of the template this way, but if it can be inlined (for such a simple body, I would think that's no problem), that's not going to hurt performance. So each volume class will be defined as

```
class MyVolumeClass : public VolumeBase<MyVolumeClass> { ... };
```